# Motor control using voice inputs from the laptop

Tags: controls, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sphinx4

My aim is to control a using voice inputs such as "Forward" and "Backward". I'm hoping to use Sphinx 4 (JAVA) for the programming part. Also i'm planning to use the laptop to give the input voice. I'm completely new to voice recognition studies. So can some one guide me where to start with and provide me a sample code in sphinx 4 to capture few simple words.

Comment: Sample code is in sphinx4 sources. See HelloWorld demo in sphinx4.

Comment: Laptop microphones are, generally, very low quality. To get decent result you will need a decent mic.